# C# remove backslash before an uppercase letter

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove one backslash occurrence before an uppercase letter

Example:

String **before**: `/G8/W7m/L/K/V/E/X/B/V/L/O/Y/M//W/At1zg==`

String **after**: `G8W7mLKVEXBVLOYM/WAt1zg==`

`String.replace` is no help, as it would remove all backslashes.

Comment: Title: "C# remove backslash *before* an uppercase letter". Question: " one backslash occurrence *after* an uppercase letter". What do you actually mean?

Comment: My intention is to remove the character **before** the backslash, as seen in my example.

Comment: Those are *forward slashes*.  This is a backslash: \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression:

```
var s = "/G8/W7m/L/K/V/E/X/B/V/L/O/Y/M//W/At1zg==";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"/(?=[A-Z])", "");
```

Comment: This also the removes the slash before lowercase letters.

Comment: Use `@"/(?=\[A-Z])"` ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
long hand looks to be working

function remake(){
    var prechange = "/G8/W7m/L/K/V/E/X/B/V/L/O/Y/M//W/At1zg==";
    var postChange = "";

    for (i=0;i<prechange.length;i++){

        if(prechange[i] === "/" ){

            if(prechange[i-1] != undefined && prechange[i-1] != "/" ){
                if(prechange[i+1] == prechange[i+1].toUpperCase() ){
                }else{
                     postChange += prechange[i];
                }
            }else if( prechange[i-1] == "/"  ){
                postChange += prechange[i];
            }

        }else{
            postChange += prechange[i];
        }

    }
    console.log(  prechange + "  " + postChange);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is in C#? Looks more like javascript